# JQuery link entire table row to anchor to trigger fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, fancybox-2

I have found multiple ways to link an entire table row to another page with jQuery. But every solution I've tried for this does not work with anchors which point to a div that triggers a fancybox.

I have the following HTML

```
<tbody class="result" data-href="#details1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" class="resultlogo">
     <img class="resultlogoimg" src="images/logos/logo-orshop.png">
    </td>
    <td class="resulthead">
     <h1><a class="detaillink" href="#details1">Orshop</a></h1>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="resultprice">
     <h1>€ 69.00</h1></td><td rowspan="2" class="resultrating">
       <span class="markbg"><h1>8,3</h1></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="resultpc"><h2>3074ES, Rotterdam</h2></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

With the following jQuery to trigger the click event:

```
$(".result").click(function() {
   window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
});
```

The `<tbody>` tag wraps 2 table rows because of the way a result row is layed out. I want to show div contents in a fancybox based on the user clicking a row (or tbody tag).

Is it not possible to use data-href with anchors?

Comment: Make sure to wrap your `tbody` inside a `table` element, otherwise your selector `$('.result')` will be empty.

Comment: You can reach anchor. `window.location = $('a[href]',this).attr("href");`

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to wrap the 2 table rows, set you `data` attributes in the `<table>` tag, and not in the `<tbody>` tag.

Then you only need a simple fancybox initialization script like:

```
$(".result").fancybox();
```

And use the fancybox's special `data` attributes to set the `href` and the `type` of content like

```
<table class="result" data-fancybox-type="inline" data-fancybox-href="#details1">...</table>
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cxpseyur/)**